# Jquery- Send params with trigger() function and receive those using click function

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using Jquery 1.4.3. I know that there are newer versions but for compatibility with an existing software we have not updated the library yet.

Im trying to get some data that it is passed using the trigger() function. The trigger function has the following params:

```
.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )
```

I would like to get those params from the .click() function which says:

```
.click( handler(eventObject) )
```

Im not sure how to get those or if I can use trigger to launch an event and some params and using the click listener I can get those. Does someone know if I can use that combination for emitting events and retrieving params?

The way Im trying is like this:

```
$("#id").trigger('click', ObjectToPass);
```

and the listener would be defined as follow:

```
$("#id").click(function(event){...})
```

What am I missing?

Comment: event.data.yourParamname

Comment: You are looking for [`event.data`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/)

Comment: @greut no, `event.data` is for data that's supplied at event _binding_ time.

Comment: What's that? What do you mean with supplied at event binding time?

Comment: @kitimenpolku you can add data when you bind the click handler (i.e. `.click(handler, data)` which then gets passed as `event.data`.  It's separate to any data sent with `.trigger()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call:

```
$("#id").trigger('click', ObjectToPass);
```

then the `ObjectToPass` is [passed as an *extra parameter*](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to the event handler:

> An array of arguments can also be passed to the `.trigger()` call, and these parameters will be passed along to the handler as well following the event object

so you can retrieve your data like this:

```
$("#id").click(function(event, data) {
     // data contains "ObjectToPass"
     ...
})
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/QXZ8K/

NB: the jQuery documentation appears inconsistent.  Whilst the text quoted above only talks about arrays, the function specification says "**extraParameters**:
Type: `Array` or `PlainObject`"

Passing an object appears to work fine in recent versions of jQuery, but may not work in 1.4.3.  In earlier versions you may need to write `.trigger(e, [ ObjectToPass ])`.

Comment: what's the downvote for?!  This is correct, per the documentation (and tested, too!)

Comment: documentation link please?

Comment: Just discovered this does not work in jquery 1.9+ when triggering click event on checkbox inputs:  http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13353

Answer (score 1):

Look @greut comment or more solution:

```
var clickEvent = new $.Event('click');
clickEvent.YourParameter = YourParameterValue;
$("#id").trigger(clickEvent);
```

and get this parameter in handler:

```
function(event) { alert(event.YourParameter); }
```